# Removing hex code ffa3 in Vim

Tags: vim, hex

I've got a file with a load of weird characters with in it that I need to get rid of.

Using `ga` on the character reveals it has the following encodings:

```
ﾣ> 65443, Hex ffa3, Octal 177643
```

But I can't seem to find it using `:%s/\%xffa3//g`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just found a way to do it by copying the character in visual mode and pasting it directly into the search and replace command. Would still like to see where I went wrong with this for future reference, though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at `:help \%x`:

> \%x2a Matches the character specified with up to two hexadecimal characters.

So Vim is actually matching the three characters `<uf>a3`. Since you have a *four-digit* hex number, you need to use `\%u`:

```
:%s/\%uffa3//g
```

#### Alternatives

You can also insert the character directly into the command line via `:help i_CTRL-V_digit` (i.e. `<C-v>uffa3`), but if you already have instances of that character in your buffer (and near your cursor!), I'd just yank that char with `yl` and insert it in the command-line via `<C-r>"`.